# ParseExact exception in C#

Tags: c#, datetime

I'm doing this:

```
DateTime.ParseExact(timestamp, "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffZ"
                , CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

it works well as I receive `timestamp` like this: `"2016-05-19T08:16:195Z"` 
but sometimes I just receive this: `"2016-05-19T08:16:19Z"` and then `ParseExact` fails. How can I update the format to include this case?

Comment: Even your first timestamp string throws the format exception with that format: `DateTime.ParseExact("2016-05-19T08:16:195Z", "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffZ", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)`

Comment: If you use Parse**Exact** you need to have the **exact** format. You could however use TryParseExact and use both formats after another.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
string[] formats = {"yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffZ", "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ"};

DateTime.ParseExact(timestamp, formats
                , CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,DateTimeStyles.None);
```

Include both formats.

Comment: @TimSchmelter: In what way? The second looks fine for the "no milliseconds" version.

Comment: You're missing a `DateTimeStyles` parameter

Comment: @JonSkeet: removed my comment, but actually it wasn't wrong, was it? The first timestamp string `"2016-05-19T08:16:191Z"` which OP claimed that it would be parsed successfully cannot be parsed with these format strings.

Comment: @TimSchmelter: Ah, I hadn't spotted the colon - I strongly suspect that's a typo. But well spotted.

Comment: @shree.pat18 modified my code. Thanks for you observation.

Comment: @JonSkeet Thanks for clearing doubts of TimSchmelter

Answer (score 2):

Try with the `DateTime.TryParseExact` method.
If it fails for your first timestamp, try to parse for the second one.

Answer (score 0):

```
DateTime dateTime = new DateTime();

if (!DateTime.TryParseExact(timestamp, "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffZ", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,DateTimeStyles.None,out dateTime))
{
    dateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(timestamp, "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.ffZ"
                                  ,CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
}
```

Comment: No need to make two calls... there's an overload for that takes multiple formats to try.

Comment: Agree! But strangely romain-aga got two upvotes for the same suggestion :)